# Label hides on scroll in chrome, but styles not changed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have button-like radio component with label. For this button used semantic-ui-react library. But for some reason when I scrolling active button, my label just disappear. Tried reproduce it in firefox - all works fine. What can cause this issue? CSS for label:

```
.ui.checkbox input.hidden+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Edit 1: we also showing some circle before label with :before, and it also disappears.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet that represents your issue?

Comment: @IhorLavs I don't think so, but i will try make some sample code.